# Look up operators programmatically by string name

Tags: python, operators

Suppose I have the following code:

```
def process(x, y, op):
    if op == 'eq':
        return x == y
    elif op == 'gt':
        return x > y
    elif op == 'lt':
        return x < y
    ... for many more operators, e.g. >=, <=, !=
```

How can I distill this down more programmatically? I'm thinking of creating a lookup like this:

```
op_lookup = {'eq': '==', 'gt': '>', 'lt': '<', ...}
```

Then doing something like this:

```
def process(x, y, op):
    return x op_lookup[op] y
```

Which **obviously** isn't valid Python...

Something like `eval` might work:

```
def process(x, y, op):
    return eval('{} {} {}'.format(x, op_lookup[op], y))
```

Which produces this, in an example:

```
>>> process(1, 1, 'eq')
True
>>> process(1, 1, 'lt')
False
```

Is there a better (safer?) way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operators as callables are hidden in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module. You can dynamically access a specific operator by its name with the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) builtin.

Demo:

```
>>> import operator         
>>> getattr(operator, 'eq')(1, 1)
True
>>> getattr(operator, 'eq')(1, 2)
False
>>> getattr(operator, 'lt')(1, 2)
True
>>> getattr(operator, 'lt')(2, 1)
False
```

We can use this to rewrite your function as follows.

```
import operator

def process(x, y, op):
    return getattr(operator, op)(x, y)
```

(Add sanity checks as required.)

Comment: Interesting -- I didn't think about accessing attributes of a module like that. I guess everything is an object in Python... (`type(operator)`)

Comment: @blacksite yes, Python is very consistent in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

The [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module is what you want:

```
>>> import operator
>>> op_lookup = {'eq': operator.eq, 'gt': operator.gt, 'lt': operator.lt}
>>> 
>>> def process(x, y, op):
...     return op_lookup[op](x, y)
... 
>>> process(1, 1, 'eq')
True
>>> process(1, 1, 'lt')
False
```